# css: использование flex для создания таблицы с дополнительным столбцом во всю ширину контейнера

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Подскажите пожалуйста как реализовать следующую вещь:

есть контейнер следующего содержания:

```
<div class = 'table'>
    <div class = 'header'>
    <div class = 'record'>
...
    <div class = 'record'>
</div>
```

необходимо, чтобы `header` занимал всю высоту контейнера `table`, а `record` располагались последовательно в 6 столбцов

Изначально у меня было сделано без `header`:

```
.table {
    display:                    flex;
    flex-wrap:                  wrap;
}

.table .record {
    flex-basis:                 calc(100% / 6);
}
```

И все работало замечательно, но вот когда потребовалось, чтобы появился новый объект `header`, который бы располагался слева и по всей высоте - возникли проблемы

Понимаю, что я могу добавить дополнительные `<div>` и решить проблему,

но возникает вопрос - а можно ли реализовать это все только листами стилей без дополнительных divов

Comment: Без дополнительных дивов - никак. Используй гриды, для подобных случаев нет  ничего лучше.

Comment: или тебе нужно header на всю ширину растянуть?В заголовке речь про ширину, в теле вопроса про высоту...

Comment: @hu-fo-of-ex, ошибся с заголовком :( имелось в виду конечно во всю высоты

т.е. гриды лучше всего?

Comment: да, гриды лучше всего

Comment: @hu-fo-of-ex, такой вопрос - а как сделать так, чтобы 1 элемент бы во всю высоту? если строк будет 100, то элемент дотянется до конца и если всего 10 строк будет, то тоже дотянется до конца (до низу)?

Comment: тут уже без доп. обертки никак не обойтись.

Comment: добавить для `.header` `align-self: stretch`